# Matlab: structures with variable name as index

Tags: matlab

I am not sure this is possible in Matlab but wanted to make sure.

I have structures as:

```
x = struct();
x.val1 = 5;
x.val2 = 7;

y = struct();
y.val1 = 15;
y.val2 = 17;
```

I want to create a structure DataStore as:

```
DataStore = struct;
DataStore(x).val1 = 5
DataStore(x).val2 = 7
DataStore(y).val1 = 15
DataStore(y).val2 = 17
```

OR

```
DataStore = struct;
DataStore('x').val1 = 5
DataStore('x').val2 = 7
DataStore('y').val1 = 15
DataStore('y').val2 = 17
```

So, I am using the name of the original structure variables as index for DataStore.

Is the above feasible ?

Edit:

I aim to use DataStore as following:

```
disp( DataStore('x').val1 )
disp( DataStore('y').val2 )
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [concatenation of structs in MATLAB](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/concatenate-structures.html)?

Comment: Why not just do `Datastore.x.val1 = 5`, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a struct, maybe with dynamic field names.

Either:

```
DataStore.x.val1=6
DataStore.x.val2=9
```

Alternative with dynamic filed names (result is the same):

```
f='x'
DataStore.(f).val1=6
DataStore.(f).val2=9
```

In case `val1` and `val2` are not just placeholders, concider replacing them with an array:

```
DataStore.(f).val(1)=6
DataStore.(f).val(2)=9
```

Comment: Worth noting is that fields can be accessed using strings as well. `disp( DataStore.('x').val1 )` or `disp( DataStore(f).val1 )`. It is kind of implied, but it might be worth being explicit with reading and writing. Still, +1